# AWS DMS with CDC to S3. How would it handle row updates and deletes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms, oracle-cdc

Let's say that I [DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) data from e.g. [MS SQLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) using [CDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) directly to S3.

If there is a row **delete** or **update** in the **source** DB, would DMS **create new** objects in S3 when those events take place? Or would it **delete** / **overwrite** the previous one?

In other words, if I want to **serialize the history of changes** of a DB to S3, would DMS with CDC to S3 do exactly that? Or would it just (continuously) mirror the current values in the source DB in S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, the first field in a .CSV record contains the letter I (insert), U (update) or D (delete) to indicate whether the row was inserted, updated, or deleted at the source database.

[source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html)

Was looking for the same thing, but it seems it doesn't serialize records in eg avro/json.